# Integrating Google OAuth API with existing user system?

Tags: php, oauth, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I have a simple user system with basic information: email and password. Instead of using the Google api as a "Sign in" feature:

`Is there any way i can "Link" the user's Youtube Channel to their account?`

`Is there a way i can Link multiple channels to a user's account? If so, how would i keep track of which user to get data from?`

I have written a few PHP Classes that take care of Google's OAuth Flow, as well as storing the access token, expiration time, and the refresh token in a database (You may think "Don't reinvent the wheel", but i prefer to learn as well by writing these classes).

As i kept going through my logic and how i would lay everything out, i just did not understand how i Link the user's account to my previous account. EG: When they login, how do i get the user's Linked channels?

Here is some of my code from my Client.php

```
public function authinticate($authorizationCode)
{
    // Now we need to do a POST request to get an Access token and a refresh token
    $post = array("grant_type" => "authorization_code", "code" => $authorizationCode, "client_id" => $this->clientID, "client_secret" => $this->clientSecret, "redirect_uri" => $this->redirectUri);
    $postText = http_build_query($post);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::Google_OAuth_Token_Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postText); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //Decode the returned values
    $responseArray = json_decode($result, true);

    // Set out values
    $this->accessToken = $responseArray['access_token'];
    $this->refreshToken = $responseArray['refresh_token'];
    $this->expiresIn = $responseArray['expires_in'];
}
```

And some from my TokenStorage Class:

```
// Store the token Data response from google, (IF reresh token is passed with a value, this means that the user JUST authorized our application, so we need to store that value)
public function storeTokenData($channelID, $accessToken, $refreshToken, $expirationTime)
{
    $firstRequest = "INSERT INTO tokens (channelID, accessToken, refreshToken, expirationTime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $expirationTime SECOND)";
    $linkedRequest = "INSERT INTO tokens (channelID, accessToken, expirationTime) VALUES (?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $expirationTime SECOND)";

    if($refreshToken == null)
    {
        if ($storeTokenData = global $mysqli->prepare($firstRequest)) 
        {    
            $storeTokenData->bind_param('sss', $channelID, $accessToken, $refreshToken); 
            if($storeTokenData->execute()) {
                // Data stored success...
                return true;
            } else {
                // Something happened...
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($storeTokenData = global $mysqli->prepare($linkedRequest)) 
        {    
            $storeTokenData->bind_param('ss', $channelID, $accessToken); 
            if($storeTokenData->execute()) {
                // Data stored success...
                return true;
            } else {
                // Something happened...
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You want to integrate your existing login solution and link users Youtube accounts.

**Recommendation**

Why not use the PHP API over at Youtube? ([API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)) Collect the login and Youtube account links into a new table and ask the user to link their accounts (when they sign in using the Youtube account) by logging into both your account and the new login? After which, the accounts can be maintained in sync because you will extend your login table with a new column of information or linked to a related table (of encrypted Youtube links). At least this is the big idea. I am sure there will be several challenges to make this work but I have seen it on other websites.

In essence build a second login flow for the Youtubers, connect via the API. Then ask them to login to their normal account and link the logins using a column in the existing table or using a new linked table with a foreign key to allow multiple Youtube pages/accounts. That would be my initial approach. The link provided above is the connection to the Youtube PHP API. I haven't needed to do this myself but if you need more precise help please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but how would i also go about linking multiple accounts to one user account? And the reason i decided not to use the API that they provide is that it is not as well documented as i would like, plus i would like the experience of creating my own PHP classes.